# ¿Por qué no existe algún sitio para el aprendizaje de idioma?

Tags: soporte

Hola amigos soy un programador y mi idioma nativo es español pero estudio inglés. No es complicado, pero en ocasiones tengo duda sobre el inglés y honestamente no creo que yo sea el único aquí aprendiendo inglés u otro idioma

¿Por qué no existe algún sitio sobre este tema de "lenguaje o lingüística" o algo similar? y si existe me pueden decir ¿Cuál es?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe [English Languaje & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) y [English Languaje Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), ambos de la red de Stack Exchange. La segunda opción parece más apropiada para lo que describes en tu caso, ya que es un sitio para hablantes de otras lenguas que quieren aprender el uso correcto del lenguaje inglés.

Comment: Vale aclarar que [english.se] es exclusivamente para lingüistas, etimólogos y entusiastas del uso del inglés, y **no para estudiantes**.